# Finding missing timestamp in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have following datasets in dataframe

```
        Time_stamp           x        y
    '2012-01-01 00:00:00'   8.97    1310.03
    '2012-01-01 00:10:00'   9.91    1684.52
    '2012-01-01 00:40:00'   9.64    1532.05
    '2012-01-01 00:50:00'   11.84   1997.87
    '2012-01-01 00:60:00'   11.69   2135.76
    '2012-01-01 01:00:00'   12.14   2149.54
    '2012-01-01 01:10:00'   13.43   2056.35
    '2012-01-01 01:20:00'   9.88    1633.45
    '2012-01-01 01:30:00'   9.01    1315.85
   '2012-01-01  01:50:00'   8.33    1141.84
```

As you can see, the data recorded in every 10 minutes. However, there is a missing timestamp and its corresponding values, for example, `'2012-01-01 00:20:00'` and `'2012-01-01 00:30:00'`. I would like to find such missing timestamp and replace their corresponding values with `nan`. Something like this

```
     timestamp            x      y
`'2012-01-01 00:20:00'`   nan    nan
`'2012-01-01 00:30:00'`   nan    nan
```

Any idea how to do this efficiently without much of lines of codes.

Answer (score 1):

First convert values to datetimes, `60Min` in `2012-01-01 00:60:00` is not valid, so replaced to `NaT`, remove mising values `NaT`, then create `DatetimeIndex` and add missing datetimes by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['Time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_stamp'].str.strip("'"), errors='coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['Time_stamp']).set_index('Time_stamp').asfreq('10Min')
print (df)
                         x        y
Time_stamp                         
2012-01-01 00:00:00   8.97  1310.03
2012-01-01 00:10:00   9.91  1684.52
2012-01-01 00:20:00    NaN      NaN
2012-01-01 00:30:00    NaN      NaN
2012-01-01 00:40:00   9.64  1532.05
2012-01-01 00:50:00  11.84  1997.87
2012-01-01 01:00:00  12.14  2149.54
2012-01-01 01:10:00  13.43  2056.35
2012-01-01 01:20:00   9.88  1633.45
2012-01-01 01:30:00   9.01  1315.85
2012-01-01 01:40:00    NaN      NaN
2012-01-01 01:50:00   8.33  1141.84
```